# calculate daily averages for 3d array

Tags: r

Is it possible to perform daily averaging over a 3d array in R?

For example:

I have a 3d array of data points on a lat/lon grid for two days.

```
lat <- 50:51
lon <- 2:3
time <- as.POSIXct(c('2009-01-01 12:00','2009-01-01 15:00','2009-01-01 17:00','2009-01-02 12:00',
                     '2009-01-02 16:00'))
j <- array(c(1:6, 11:16, 21:26), c(2,2,5))
dim(j)
[1] 2 2 5
```

where the first dimension refers to the latitude, the second refers to longitude, and the third refers to time (i.e. the data at each lat/lon through time).

How could I calculate the daily averages of these values and return a daily averaged 3d array?

The return array should have dimensions of

> dim(j)
>       [1] 2 2 2

where the time dimensions would correspond to:

```
new_time <- as.POSIXct(c('2009-01-01','2009-01-02))
```

Is this possible?

Without taking into account the different days, I can perform 3d averaging with:

```
apply(j, c(1,2), mean)
```

but I'm unsure on how to perform the averaging over selected days.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Reshape your data and use the usual split-apply-combine functions.

Comment: I'd rather not reshape the data, as in actual fact the data is on a global grid at 0.25 deg resolution, thus would get pretty big.

Comment: Well, then you either need to use inefficient loops or write something with Rcpp. I would first try if reshaping is possible.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Ok just to make sure, in your example, there are 5 days, right?</strike>

If you want to select certain days, e.g, the 1st, 3rd and 5th, you can specify them as follows:

```
> apply(j[,,c(1,3,5)], c(1,2), mean)
     [,1]     [,2]
[1,]   13 6.333333
[2,]   14 7.333333
```

**EDIT**

Ok, here is a work around:

```
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
```

If you are interested in unique days:

```
# get days
tx <- day(time)
> tx
[1] 1 1 1 2 2
```

Get the unique days and count them:

```
# unique days
txu <- unique(tx)

# number of unique days
d <- length(unique(tx))
```

Create a dataframe to hold all your data

```
# create a df with days
df <- data.frame(day=1:d)
```

Find the indecies of the entries corresponding to each days and add them in a new column

```
# add a column with entries corresponding to each days 
df <- df %>% 
        mutate(days_entries=map(day, function(x)  which(tx %in% txu[x]) ))

> df
  day days_entries
1   1      1, 2, 3
2   2         4, 5
```

Add the means of the values for each day in a new column

```
df <- df %>% 
        mutate(day_mean=map(days_entries, 
                            {function(x) apply(j[,,x], c(1,2), mean)}
                            )
               )
```

Put all means in one array:

```
> k <- array( c( sapply(df$day_mean, function(x) x)) , dim = c( 2 ,2 ,d ) )
    > dim(k)
    [1] 2 2 2
    > k
    , , 1

             [,1]      [,2]
    [1,] 6.333333  9.666667
    [2,] 7.333333 10.666667

    , , 2

         [,1] [,2]
    [1,]   23   12
    [2,]   24   13
```

Comment: There are two days in the example. See the time stamps. You have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Yeah I misunderstood it, please check the edited answer. I hope I got it this time.